Does Fubini theorem apply in this case?
I was trying to do some self-studying and learning more about Fubini or Tonelli's theorem, and I came across this problem maybe someone can help me with (excuse me if this is too trivial, I am very new to this area of applications).
Let us say I want to integrate a non-negative continuous function $g(x,y,z)$} mapping from a region $K$ defined as $0\leq z\leq yx$ and $x\in[0,a]$, $y\in[0,a]$:
$$
\iiint\limits_Kg(x,y,z)\ dxdydz
$$
How can I find the appropriate integration order in this case? I think that the easy way is through $dzdydx$:
$$
\int^{a}_{0}\int^{a}_{0}\int^{xy}_{0}g(x,y,z)\ dzdxdy
$$
If I am not wrong, Fubini-Tonelli says that the integral is the same for the other order of permutations $dxdydz,\;dydxdz,$... etc. But I don't think there is a way to find the boundaries for those orders in this case.
My question: Is it possible to write the boundaries with respect to the order $dxdydz$ for the above example? I cannot find a way given the dependence between the variables.
Otherwise, am I not applying the theorem correctly? Finally, is it possible where there is a case that Fubini applies but one of the iterated orders of integration does not have boundaries that can be written explicitly?
I want to say that I am also not very familiar with measure-theory.
Thank you!

You may have to write iterated integrals in the other orders as a sum of two or more integrals. In your case, however, for example, the projection of the region onto the $xz$-plane is given by $0\le x\le a$, $0\le z\le ax$, and then for fixed $x,z$,  $y$ varies from $z/x$ to $a$ (when $x=z=0$, you need a separate rule, of course). You might find (parts of) lectures 5 and 6 in my MATH3510 YouTube lectures helpful.

Thanks for thr comment! Could you elaborate a bit more on which order you are choosing? Also what you mean exactly by needing a separate rule when x=z=0?

What I said in words amounts to the iterated integral $$\int_0^a\int_0^{ax}\int_{z/x}^a dy,dz,dx,$$ with the understanding that $z/x$ is meant to be $0$ when $x=z=0$.

Thanks again! One last comment if you may, do you agree with my interpretation of the region above for order dzdxdy?

Yes, sure. That one is the easy one.
